# Travel to Australia with new passport (with visa in old passport)

Tags: visas, passports, australia, passport-renewals

I was granted a visa to Australia few months ago. I’d like to travel to Australia in few days. However, I’ve just renewed my passport and I don’t have enough time to inform them about my passport renewal. Can I travel to Australia by carrying both my old and my new passports?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the Australia Department of Immigration and Border Protection, you need to [notify Australia of your new passport](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/change-in-situation/passport-details) before you travel, even if you have a visa label in your old passport. Australian visas are linked to your passport number, and travelers might not have a visa label in their passports at all.

If you read the form instructions for [the notification form](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/form-listing/forms/929.pdf), it states that [you can complete this form online](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/help-support/applying-online-or-on-paper/online#passport). So you may be able to do this quickly enough to be able to travel.

Note that the form instructions state that you will *not* receive a reply. You can log in to [ImmiAccount](https://online.immi.gov.au/ola/app) to check the status.

If your old passport has a visa label in it, you should bring it with you when you travel. Do not try to remove the label and place it in your new passport.

Comment: What is the latest on this? I have a new passport and old cancelled passport with valid visa. The visa is electronic and travel document on visa is old passport.

Comment: @TejasUnnikrishnan That IS the latest on this.