# Renew British passport which includes visa for return to Australia

Tags: visas, australia, passport-renewals

I’m an Australian permanent resident with an expired British passport which includes my visa to return to Australia after travelling overseas. When I renew my passport, is the visa automatically renewed or do I do that separately?

Comment: Can't speak for Australia. But when I changed passports some years ago I still had a valid Japanese visa in my old passport. I simply took my old passport with me and showed the border guard both

Answer (score 18):

Australian visas are now electronic, and linked to your passport number. If you renew your passport you must tell Australian Immigration so that they can link your new passport to your visa. If you don't do this you won't be able to re-enter Australia as a resident.

<sup>[Source](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/resident-return-visa-155-157#When)</sup>

In many cases you can [do this online](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/change-in-situation/passport-details). The same page also links to the form you'll need if you're not able to renew online.

The thing to remember here is that you **must** do this before you return to Australia.

Answer (score 6):

The British passport office cannot renew another country’s visa. You will need to ask that country’s immigration agency or body to do it. The real question is whether you can travel to Australia using a visa in an expired passport, and we [have an answer on that](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47745/travel-to-australia-with-new-passport).

Answer (score 5):

I renewed my British passport from Australia and then left Australia without thinking about it. When I went to check in at the airport, I was told to wait while somebody phoned Canberra to transfer my visa to the new passport.

I would advise being more pro-active than me.